# Reset timeused coupon for one customer

Tags: coupon

I want to reset the usedtime for one customer back to 0 that he can use this coupon again. I tried to change thing in the sql but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the usages for coupons are stored in the table `salesrule_coupon_usage`.
So if you want to remove all usages for a certain coupon run this query.

```
DELETE FROM 
    salesrule_coupon_usage 
WHERE
    coupon_id = coupon id goes here AND
    customer_id = customer id goes here
```

if you want to update the number of usages to a certain value run

```
UPDATE
    salesrule_coupon_usage 
SET 
    times_used = number of times used go here
WHERE
    coupon_id = coupon id goes here AND
    customer_id = customer id goes here
```

Comment: didnt work on Magento Commerce 2.4.0 p1
The table is present and post deleting the coupon doesnt work. reset and ran the sales_rule index as well